# what should be the cron expression if job should run first monday of every quarter(jan, apr,july, oct) at 11:00 am EST?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-glue, scheduler

I wrote following cron expression but aws say invalid cron expression. Im trying to setup schedule of glue job.

0 0 11 ? 1/3 2#1 *

tried following cron expression but its showing as invalid in aws

0 0 11 ? 1/3 2#1 *

0 11 ? 1/3 2#1 *

Comment: Instead of `1/3` for the month, why not just specify the actual months: `JAN,APR,JUL,OCT`  see the month example in the `, (comma)` details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-cron-expressions.html

Comment: even this expression is invalid 0 0 11 ? JAN,APR,JUL,OCT 2#1 . I think problem lies in day of the week?

Comment: This site will help you having a good comprehension of cron expressions, after setting you have examples of the next running days. Example 0 0 * 1,4,7,10 1 “At 00:00 on Monday in January, April, July, and October.”

https://crontab.guru/

Comment: It looks like you may be using the EventBridge cron syntax, while the Glue cron documentation doesn't mention the # thing for day of month. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-data-warehouse-schedule.html You might try this to use EventBridge https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/starting-workflow-eventbridge.html

Comment: @ ale sosa well problem is that job should execute only on FIRST Monday of every quarter which is why that expression wont work

Comment: @Mark B I didn't knew glue cron don't accept # wildcard even though cloudwatch do.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#CronExpressions

Answer (score -2):

This can't be done using a single expression. At least not by the legacy Unix (i.e., POSIX) cron implementations since they have no concept of "first monday" (or any related concept; e.g., "second tuesday"). You'll have to explicitly specify the dates of interest. For example,

```
0 0 3 jul * # july 2023
0 0 2 oct * # october 2023
0 0 1 jan * # january 2024
0 0 1 apr * # april 2024
```

So unless you are using a cron implementation that implements a richer DSL (domain specific language) you'll have to use a pattern like the one above and update each day after that event has passed.

Comment: This question isn't about legacy Unix cron.